# How to prove using big-O

Tags: big-o

Im currently having a problem with big O notation. I have the following question which I am trying to figure out.

I currently have the formula: T(n) is O(f(n)) and I must use this to prove directly from the definition of big O that 3n^2+11n+6 is O(n^2).

I was wondering if anybody could possibly help me figure out this problem as I am having trouble working it out.

Comment: You should already know the [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of big-O.

Comment: Yes I know the mathematical definition of big O already which is T(n) <= Cxf(n) for all values of n >= N. However I am unsure on how to use this to prove the problem above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help:
For n≥k, there is a constant, let's name it "c" which satisfies 3n^2 + 11n + 6 ≤ c∗n^2. 
Let's say we pick k = 1.
We know that n^2 ≥ n^2 ≥ n ≥ 1

So :
        `3n^2 + 11n + 6 ≤ 3n^2 + 11n^2 + 6n^2  =>3n^2 + 11n + 6 ≤ 20n^2`

Now, let c = 20.
=>complexity is O(n2).